# Manage Data Financial Year Wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I am developing account system. Let's take one example. `ABC` is the one of the account name and in year `2010-11` opening balance of `ABC` account is `40000`. now end of this year closing balance of `ABC` account is `10000`. Now what i want is, in year `2011-12` opening balance of `ABC` account is must be `10000` and if i want to see report of year `2010-11` then it should display value of previous year that means `40000` instead of `10000`. I don't know how to design my database so that i can manage data financial year wise. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid this is business rules, probably easier to implement in the business level instead of the database layer

Comment: actually that has nothing to do with business rules. It is trivial in any properly designed (also legally) accounting system in which you store the new account value in the last transaction (with a timestamp).

Comment: This is a very typical business requirement, and it should be dealt on application level not at database design level. In you database just store the Account information like name, balance and datetime column to capture withdrawals and deposits. and then design your sql queries which at run time get you an Account's balance on a certain dates what ever you financial year start date and end dates are to calculate opening and closing balance of an account.

Comment: Keeping in mind financial year is different in every country and you might have a multinational company as a client who is located in UK but works by USA's financial year. In this case if you have handled this on a database design level you will end up in pretty ugly situation.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the Opening Balance Table with AccountID, FinancialYearID, Balance
for this you would have two entries in this table one for 2010-20111 YearID 4000
and second for 2011-2012 YearID 10000